# good index for order by syntax mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Consider this query:

```
Select * 
from table1 
where field1=x and field2=y 
order by field3
```

I know that index (field1,field2) will make performance better.

What about field3? Will indexing make `order by` better or not?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link http://www.linux.org/article/view/what-are-database-indexes- you will give you some help... I think the index in field3 is important if the amount of records in the table is several.